# Jboss 7.1.1 Final to WildFly 10 migration - SQL Error: 17003, SQLState: 99999

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, wildfly-9, wildfly-10

We have a basic application which inserts data to an Oracle DB using hibernate. The application itself is working on jboss 7.1.1 , java se 7, depends on hibernate 3.5.6.

However when we move the application to wildfly 1.0.0 or 9.0.2, java se 8, the insert is getting the exception below

```
14:22:12,224 ERROR [com.enk.ne.frontend.ws.NotificationEngineWsInputImpl] Error in processing CreateProvisiningBaseServiceImpl: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [insert into NE_NOTIFICATION_INPUT (CREATION_DATE, FILE_NAME, INPUT_TYPE, INPUT_ID) values (?, ?, 'FE', ?)]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17003]; could not insert: [com.enk.ne.db.model.FeInput]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not insert: [com.enk.ne.db.model.FeInput].
```

What could be the reason for this ? Any ideas ? the functionality works correctly when app is deployed to JBoss 7.1.1 Final.

Comment: Are you bundling Hibernate? It looks like your app is using Hibernate 3, but WildFly 9 defaults to Hibernate 4.

Comment: yes, we are bundling hibernate with the application. So I am expecting wildfly to take the hibernate in my app into consideration. Am I missing a point ?

Comment: WildFly will prefer it's own Hibernate dependencies if you have the JPA subsystem enabled.

Comment: FYI - check the [JBoss Windup migration tool](https://github.com/windup/windup/wiki).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is JPA version. Wildfly 10 uses jpa 2.1 which requires upgrade in Discriminator mapping. Details can be found in answer below
[java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index in wildfly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599888/java-sql-sqlexception-invalid-column-index-in-wildfly/36639557#36639557)